# Perl::Mechanize: running a simple crawler with a loop [multiple queries]

Tags: mysql, perl, parsing, mechanize, lwp

currently ironing out a way to parse the data of a page: http://www.foundationfinder.ch/

i love to do it in Perl: Well - i am just musing which is the best way to do the job. 
Guess that i am in front of a nice learning curve.  ;)  This task will give me some nice Perl lessions. At the moment it goes abit over my head...;-)

So here is a sample-page:

[image: see the resultpage]

... and as i thought i can find all 790 resultpages within a certain range between Id= 0 and Id= 100000 i thought, that i can go the way with a loop:

http://www.foundationfinder.ch/ShowDetails.php?Id=11233&InterfaceLanguage=&Type=Html
http://www.foundationfinder.ch/ShowDetails.php?Id=927&InterfaceLanguage=1&Type=Html
http://www.foundationfinder.ch/ShowDetails.php?Id=949&InterfaceLanguage=1&Type=Html
http://www.foundationfinder.ch/ShowDetails.php?Id=20011&InterfaceLanguage=1&Type=Html
http://www.foundationfinder.ch/ShowDetails.php?Id=10579&InterfaceLanguage=1&Type=Html

i thought i can go the Perl-Way but i am not very very sure:  I was trying to use LWP::UserAgent  on the same URLs [see below] with different query arguments, and i am wondering if LWP::UserAgent provides  a way for us to loop through the query arguments? I am not sure that LWP::UserAgent has a method for us to do that. Well - i sometimes heard that it is easier to use Mechanize. But is it really easier!?

BTW; But if i am going the PHP way i could do it with Curl - couldnt i!?

Here is my approach: I tried to figure it out. And i digged deeper in the Manpages and Howtos. We can have a loop constructing the URLs and use Curl - repeatedly

As noted above: here we have some resultpages;

http://www.foundationfinder.ch/ShowDetails.php?Id=11233&InterfaceLanguage=&Type=Html
http://www.foundationfinder.ch/ShowDetails.php?Id=927&InterfaceLanguage=1&Type=Html

Alternatively we can add a request_prepare handler that computes and add the query
arguments before we send out the request.

Again: What is aimed: i want to parse the data and afterwards i want to store it in a local MySQL-database

should i define a extern_uid !?

and go like this:

```
for my $i (0..10000) {
  $ua->get('http://www.foundationfinder.ch/ShowDetails.php?Id=', id => 21, extern_uid => $i);
  # process reply
}
```

Well but now i get stuck- i need help - can i do the job like this!?

regards

zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont do it like this. Use **HTTP live headers** (Firefox Plugin) or eqv. to see what the javasript does behind the scenes while you select what you need from [here](http://www.foundationfinder.ch/) to get to that page (with the table).

To get the data from the table, use `HTML::TableExtract` or `HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath` if you want to use XPath

If you do want to iterate over the queries, just create another var:

```
my $a = 'http://www.foundationfinder.ch/ShowDetails.php?Id=' . $q . '&InterfaceLanguage=&Type=Html';
```

and increment $q as you go, make sure the page is valid before trying to load it with `get`

Comment: hello SoulSurfer, many thanks great to hear from you! I never have worked with liveHeaders in FF. Can you give me a helping hand - (also in Table Extract or Treebuilder!? - to  get afirst glance of the XPAth that i am workin on. Love to hear from you! greetings

Comment: Hi SoulSurfer - thx alot. I  am sure that i have to make sure that the page is valid before trying to load it with get. Valid point! Tx so far.  I will try to get along with this first aid! Hope i manage the task!!

Comment: Hello Soulsurfer: Many thanks for the quick reply. To be honest. i am not experienced in HTML::TableExtract or TML::TreeBuilder::XPath 
So can you give me some first steps to do it this way. The TableExtract's idea of doing the job is very interesting! Can you give me a helping hand and show how this solution would look like!? Look forward to hear from you!  BTW .- you would help me and my pupils alot - this is a task that i do for my school-class (and the pupils would be very happy)... look forward to hear from you...;-)

Comment: @zero: it works so much better if you do what you can, then explain where you got stuck or had something go wrong.

Comment: hello ysth - okay i do so - and come back here later... untill soon